# What is the best way to setup 3 HDDs with 3 OS on one computer?

Tags: linux, osx, windows, dual-boot, performance

I am building a new PC, I am a developer of whatever people want me to make, but I personally like to code games.

To do this, I have a simple set of requirements:

1. Machine must run Windows 7, to run recent AAA games, some old games I have projects (and require DX7), and install lots of versions of MSVC (and related tools)
2. Machine must run Linux, it is my desktop of choice, and has the best dev tools in general (Valgrind for example), also is an obvious POSIX platform to develop POSIX stuff.
3. Machine must run OSX, because my most profitable contracts are for iOS and OSX... (no matter how much I insist clients to accept projects for other platforms).

I don't care about OS boot time, or application launch times, but I DO care about compilation times, time to launch stuff I am debugging, being able to record videos fast, being able to run Windows Performance Tools and dump several gigabytes of performance data without degrading the performance of whatever I am profiling.

This is my first time with a multiple-HDD machine.

Ideas so far:

1. Split each HDD in 3, OS, SWAP, DATA, but install the OSes "interleaved", for example OSX "/" on HDD1, OSX SWAP on HDD2, OSX "/home" on HDD3. This theoretically allow me to use all 3 HDDs at once, and allow me to use the bios boot selection to boot OSes (instead of needing some funky bootloader). But it probably wastes space, as OSX /home probably will be used for 3gb, while Windows data partition would need more than 1TB.
2. split HDD1 between 3 OSes, and hope I can figure how to boot them... And use the other 2 HDDs for RAID0. Sounds hard to do and risky, but maybe is faster than 1
3. Same as 1, but use some tech to create a raid-like data partition out of the "data" part of the 3 HDDs. I don't even know if that is possible...
4. RAID5 all 3 HDDs, use as if it was just one giant HDD, partitioning it between the 3 OSes (sounds hard to do).
5. Use VM to boot OSes? I have no idea how that works, I tried to find out but only got confused, I DO know that the motherboard+CPU support Intel VT-d

I can't afford an SSD now, also the HDDs are 1TB WD Blacks from 2013, that have notoriously bad random seek times (16ms, while older WD HDDs had 12ms or less) but is one of the fastest sequential read/write speeds available (160 megabyte/s is common, some people reported more).

But I DO plan in buying SSDs later, but I don't know if an OS can be easily moved to an SSD later, also I never saw an SSD in person, I don't know their performance characteristics, or if they can be merged with HDDs (using RAID or something similar) to improve HDD performance directly (using SSD as some kind of cache to speed-up random read/write).

Comment: Question originally was on SuperUser, but people there said hackintosh is not allowed there and offtopic, and instead that I should ask here.

Comment: Instead of using real harddisks, allow booting from USB and run any OS.

Comment: is that reliable? also USB write speeds last I checked used to be really slow, and OSes do tend to write in their own partition a bit.

And how much is a big enough USB, the same as an SSD no?

Comment: went to read some benchmarks, seemly with USB 3.0 even the read performance is not that good, with the average pendrive peaking at 100 megabytes per second (slower than WD Black 160 megabyte per second), and random seek time being better than HDD, but not much.

USB 3.0 has the same theoretical capacity (per the standard) as SATA 3.0

As for price, a 128gb Kingston USB 3.0 pendrive here costs 170 USD

Comment: Don't do that @speeder. If your setup is intended to last for some time a hard drive is the solution of choice.

Comment: I need the computer to last for about 5 years... I hope the 5 year warranty of the WD Blacks 1TB is because WD really hope they will last 5 year!

Comment: At least for linux, a usb based boot device is quite adequate. My current storage is centos 7.2 on 2x64GB usb sticks, in mdraid mirror. swap, /home and any other big data is on actual HDDs (zfs over 14 disks).  When a usb starts to "act up" I just replace and rebuild the raid live. No idea about osx, but windows should be ok with this too.

Comment: Regarding performance -that's a red herring - After boot, my rig doesn't write to the usb except for shutdown. kernel image lives in memory, and everything else (incl. compilation) is from data disks. /tmp, /var/log,/var/spool and  /var/cache are all tmpfs.

Comment: Dani_l what about installing new applications, and editing configurations?

Comment: If you care at all about disk performance, don't use RAID-5.  And if you care at all about your data, don't use RAID-0 (except as part of a RAID-10/1+0 array).   Either use only two of your drives in RAID-1, or get a fourth drive and use all four drives in RAID-10.

Comment: BTW, if you want the RAID to work for all three OS-es, your only option is a real hardware raid card.  The fakeraid built into many motherboards will probably work OK in both Windows and Linux, but probably not for OSX (because it's not real hardware raid, it's software raid relying on a driver on the OS).

Comment: So, no option 2, or 4 of my list I guess? (meaning I should use 1, 3 or 5)

Answer (score 1):

I of course can't give you **the answer** to your situation, but I wan't to try and give you some ideas on it.

First of all: **use SSDs**!

I understood that you can't affort them yet, **but** you will **definitely** love them once you have them. And I assume it is a better idea to do this whole setup once and for all, not now and in a few month you have to do it all over again.

My idea on your setup:

1. Get at least one big SSD as your system drive

   - Put your OSes on this drive and configure it for multiboot
   - Also put the swap partitions there
2. Use your HDDs with RAID 5 as a data drive

   - Format it as you like with one big partition for everything or separated by OS

As an alternative for the 1. solution use an HDD, preferably the same size of the planned SSD and set everything up. Later you can clone the drive to your SSD using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) for example.

**Miscellaneous**

As [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) said in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277600/what-is-the-best-way-to-setup-3-hdds-with-3-os-on-one-computer#comment482625_277618) you don't have to worry about heavy I/O on your SSD, as [this article](https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead) shows.

Comment: Ideally this is what I want to do... but I sadly can't :( Thus why I made the question in first place. (also, doesn't swap quickly destroy cheaper SSDs?)

Comment: I don't know your situation but I would assume it's worth waiting until you can afford the SSDs. And someone correct me if I am wrong,  but as long as you don't extensively use swap, I don't see a problem. Mine is running since one year without a problem. And if you happen to use all of your RAM, let's say for a VM for example, the swap on SSD will save you from a system lockup.

Comment: I can't "wait" to afford SSD, the machine I am building is my work tool (I am a programmer), if I "wait" I will have zero income, and will never afford it ;) EDIT: about swap: windows write to swaps a lot, windows is very swap-write happy

Comment: I hate Windows... Well you don't have a fourth drive have you? My idea would be to use a small HDD (same size as the to be purchased SSD) and simply clone it once you have the SSD. EDIT: HDD to SSD cloning is no problem.

Comment: the days are long past when SSD write endurance was an issue for any kind of normal (or even absurdly excessive) use.  Modern SSDs are specified to be capable of multiple complete rewrites every day for many years....far more than any normal usage will be.  Here's an article from March last year on stress-testing SSD writes until they died - it was hard work, and took deliberate effort: http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead

Comment: Thanks @cas for the information, I had the same in mind. I will include your link in my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: feel free to use anything from my comments.

Comment: @speeder, how is it going? Are you making any progress?

Comment: the HDDs don't arrived yet! Meanwhile I am now trying to design a computer case (I didn't found one for sale in my country... )

Comment: Also, I will need now 4 OSes (one AAA game company maybe will ask for my help to fix a legacy game of theirs that don't work on Win10... of course if they ask, I will have to also install Win10 to test if my fix work or not)

Comment: As we are talking of VMs there is no problem in setting up a bunch of OSes. Also what solution do you prefer currently?

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:
You can also just buy a second hand brand name workstation (or build a custom one but I think it's not worth it) with 32/64gigs of ram and 2 x 8 core Xeon E5-2670s for instance (+hyperthreading, thus having 32 CPU threads), with 3 drives in RAID5 and install an OS as a hypervisor and have your 3 OS's in virtual machines. This way you can have them up and running all 3 at a time if you wish and this kind of rig is powerful enough for mostly anything. In case you need more power for a machine, you can reassign the hardware also.

Comment: that is ludicrously expensive... O.O and here I was thinking my build was already kickassing enough (i5 with 32gb of ram)

Comment: not necessarily.....for max 1000 bucks you will surely find depending on your location also (I just bought one myself on an ebay auction) and IMHO that is affordable

Comment: Where I live importing a 1000 USD machine will cost about 100% of the value+shipping price, thus to ship and pay customs of an 15kg machine it can easily cost me 1000 USD (for the machine) + 1600 USD, crossing a threshold that make insurance necessary, bumping total price to 3000 USD+

Comment: oooops that's not nice......

Comment: mind, you, keep your answer, it is a good one for people reading from more sane countries :)

Comment: Oh, I have a question related to your answer: my machine DOES have VT-d, and a GPU, can I boot windows from a VM easily and have good games performance? where I should plug my monitor? (mobo port, or gpu port?), and can Linux use the GPU after I shut down the VM?

Comment: you don't need dual 8-core Xeons to run 3 VMs.  an i5 with at least 4 cores (actual cores, not hyperthreading) will be enough.   Actually, only 2 VMs are needed - either windows, linux, or mac can run VMs for the other two OSes.   If windows gaming performance is important, you're probably better off using Win7 as the host OS with Linux and OSX in VirtualBox VMs.

Comment: Even with VT-d? I've heard taht with VT-d and giving GPU to the VM, it can reach 95% of the "native" performance when gaming

Comment: If you don't mind losing the 5% of native GPU performance, then you can use linux or osx as the host OS.  You'll probably gain some disk performance to compensate, and (with linux as host) you can use `mdadm` or `lvm` (or even `zfsonlinux`) for the file-systems and the VMs' virtual disks.

Comment: BTW, many windows games will run on linux using `wine`.  But each game is different - some work perfectly (in fact, some work better on wine than they do on native windows), some work OK-ish, and some don't work at all or with serious flaws.  check wine's appdb at  https://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: One more thought: What about setting up the hypervisor on bare metal and install all OSes as VMs? I have no know-how with that yet, but xen for example should be able to do this I think. I guess that would be the the VM solution with the best performance.

Comment: Yup you get the best performance that way, but in that case you need a remote computer to connect to your VMs. Bare metal hypervisors only have a console of their own, you cannot see the screen of a VM (there are exceptions I guess, like Windows Hyper-V Server with Desktop, but that's not exactly a bare-metal hypervisor)

Comment: I assumed there would be a possibility.. But anyways, let's see whether @speeder may take this into consideration.

Comment: Some great information there! Also, I was thinking about this when I wrote the original question, the "3" option is because I've heard, but I am not sure if it is accurate, that mdadm, lvm and zgsonlinux can unite partial parts of HDDs into some stripped array. and the "5" option because I was already considering booting windows only on VM, to avoid dual-booting, and because some people told me I could install the VM on lvm/mdadm/zfsonlinux and take advantage of the stripped speed.

Comment: You can absolutely do that, install an OS, on its software raid5, and use the other two in VMs. On a a lot of motherboards already, have also the possibility to create a software raid5 from its BIOS(without having a raid card), so your OS will see one hard drive. A software raid is using CPU time as it has no dedicated hardware to handle the raid (as on raid cards).

Comment: 1. the phrase "bare-metal hypervisor" is mostly marketing hype.  Linux's KVM is "bare-metal", but you can also run a complete Linux OS on that same bare metal at the same time.  2. if you're interested in raid because of the performance benefit of striping, then don't use raid-5.  use raid-1 or raid-10 (or mirrored pairs in zfs).  raid-5 (and raid-z in zfs) is slow, especially on writes - you can improve that with a non-volatile write cache, but for that you need (expensive) hardware raid.

Comment: as you're a newcomer to virtualisation, i'd suggest that VirtualBox will be much easier to configure (compared to,say, `kvm`) for maximum GPU performance in the VMs.

Comment: No it is not a marketing hype at all. A bare-metal hypervisor gives direct access to the hardware and resources for the virtual machines resulting in better performance, it can be managed centrally , and it has advanced features for resource management, high availability and security, and usually it is easy to delpoy remotely. Unlike this, a host-based hypervisor is based on an OS, this OS has to be installed and configured, the virtual machines have to access the hardware through the drivers of the host OS -impacting the VMs' performance. Host often steals resources from the VMs.

Comment: Every "bare metal" hypervisor either uses or *is* an OS.  e.g. linux with kvm, and vmware used to be based on linux but now has their own minimalist OS (but they still steal GPLed code from linux for SCSI and other drivers). Everything you claim as a bare-metal hypervisor feature is a generic VM management feature common to many/all hypervisors.  "bare-metal" IS mostly a marketing term.  The only hypervisors that it might be inappropriate to call 'bare-metal' are those that run as a user, like Virtual box.  and even virtualbox requires kernel support in the form of the `vbox*.ko` modules.

Comment: @cas As you wish. "Bare-metal" is absolutely not a marketing term and there are significant performance and functional differences between a bare-metal and a host-based virtualization. There is a whole industry based on this. If you would have worked for years with a bare-metal hypervisor in a datacenter environment having tens of thousands of servers, you'd probably know the difference. Also you can just google the terms "bare-metal vs host-based" to read a bit more about it. Or you can keep your strong belief. As this is turning into flaming i'll stop here and i wish you good luck.

Comment: you are entirely missing the point.  there is no difference between "host-based" and "bare-metal" virtualisation.  They're the same damn thing.  as i said before EVERY kind of virtualisation runs on an operating system.  that is unavoidable, something has to interface with the hardware and that is called an OS.  The Linux kernel happens to make an excellent OS for virtualisation.  It just so happens that you can also choose to run OTHER software on the same kernel at the same time - and, in fact, must run some - to provide a shell, cron, and other necessary/useful daemons.